# $C^{1}$ convex function but not $C^{1,1}$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

We have known that a convex function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is Frechet differentiable iff $f\in C^1$ (class of Frechet differentiable functions with continuous gradients). This motivates to the following question:

Could we construct a convex function $f\in C^1$ but $f\notin C^{1,1}$ (class of Frechet differentiable functions with locally Lipschitz gradients)?

Thank you for all guidance and references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, $f(x)=\frac23\lvert x\rvert^{3/2}=\int_0^x \lvert t\rvert^{1/2}\operatorname{sgn}t\,dt$ is convex and $C^1$, but $f'(x)=\lvert x\rvert^{1/2}\operatorname{sgn}x$ is not Lipschitz continuous in any neighbourhood of $0$. More generally, integrate your favourite monotone increasing continuous function which is not locally Lipschitz and you'll obtain a counterexample in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Could we construct example for function on convex compact set?

Comment: Like the restriction of this one to $[-1,1]$?

Comment: Could we construct example for strictly convex or strongly convex function?

Comment: This example *is* strictly convex.

Comment: Thanks. How about strong convexity?

Comment: I presume it is also $\frac23$-strongly convex in the neighbourhood of $0$ where $f(x)-\frac13 x^2$ is convex (not globally, though).